# Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReviewsKeyType' TS ERROR

Tags: javascript, typescript

I got this TS Error, can anyone explain me what I am doing wrong ?

```
Type '{ key: string; number: number | undefined; }[]' is not assignable to type 'IReviewsRoute[]'.
  Type '{ key: string; number: number | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'IReviewsRoute'.
    Types of property 'key' are incompatible.
      Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReviewsKeyType'.ts(2322)
```

Model:

```
export type ReviewsKeyType = 'ONE' | 'TWO' | 'THREE' | 'FOUR' | 'FIVE';

export interface IReviewsRoute {
  key: ReviewsKeyType;
  number: number | undefined;
}
```

Data

```
    const ROUTES: IReviewsRoute[] = [
      {
        key: 'ONE',
        number: 1
      },
      {
        key: 'TWO',
        number: 2
      },
      {
        key: 'THREE',
        number: 3
      },
      {
        key: 'FOUR',
        number: 4
      },
      {
        key: 'FIVE',
        number: 5
      }
    ];
```

Why he say string is not assignagble to type reviewskeytpe ? I didnt put a string anywhere

Comment: What Typescript version are you compiling with?

Comment: @MichaelOstrovsky 4.5.5

Comment: I've tried researching why you're encountering this error with the Typescript Sandbox here -https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwBuBLYB3AZwGlhEAVZVAXjgHIB5AOQFFa4AfOsgdXrc9pkAEmmasOdAGL0Aqmn5SAkgDVWAbgBQG0JFhxsAOxjAoAMwCGAY1SKMOfATQQArsbgBvDXG9wA1qQAuOAIYKEMAc00fOANnAFsAIxMg2MSTCWcDABNgU0NgLM0AXy1LCAMQ9FkyZgBlINssXEInV2AAbQBdOBp2rx9PaOj-RCCGFloAGn6hmPikqCCARhm4Iunowdm-QK5eKdXo1IWggCZV9dWt2ZGx4VFWDe3j5LgAZgun72uh26lZeRfIYvRZwAAsnyuhx8f1okhUj2h3hBQQArBcNJ01EA but I'm not encountering it. Maybe some extra context is missing from the question?